# Template parse errors: 'md-form-field' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Angular 4 and Angular Material 2. For the following code :

```
<form>
  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput [ngModel]="userName" placeholder="User" [formControl]="usernameFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="usernameFormControl.hasError('required')">
      This is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
    <input mdInput [ngModel]="password" placeholder="Password" [formControl]="passwordFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="passwordFormControl.hasError('required')">
      This is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!usernameFormControl.valid || !passwordFormControl.valid">Login</button>
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

I am getting an error:

> Template parse errors: **'md-form-field' is not a known element**:
>   1. If 'md-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("   [ERROR ->]

Could you please help me where I am missing?

Following is my **`app.module.ts`** code where I have imported material modules:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdCoreModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdExpansionModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdNativeDateModule,
  MdPaginatorModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  MdRippleModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdSidenavModule,
  MdSliderModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdSnackBarModule,
  MdSortModule,
  MdTableModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdChipsModule,
    MdCoreModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdExpansionModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdListModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    MdPaginatorModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdRadioModule,
    MdRippleModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdSliderModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdSortModule,
    MdTableModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    CdkTableModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Since **`2.0.0-beta.12`**, **`md`** prefix has been removed in favor of **`mat`** prefix. See this [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta12-marble-mustache-2017-10-05) for details:

> All "md" prefixes have been removed. See the [**deprecation notice**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix) in the
>   beta.11 notes for more information.

After the update, **`<md-form-field>`** should be changed to **`<mat-form-field>`**. Also, **`MdFormFieldModule`** and **`MdInputModule`** should be changed to **`MatFormFieldModule`** and **`MatInputModule`**:

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ....
  ]
```

Here is a link to [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-ejor4l?file=app/app.component.html) demo using **`2.0.0-beta.12`**.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

**`<md-form-field>`** was introduced in [**2.0.0-beta.10**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-d%C3%A9coupage-panjandrum-2017-08-29). See below from the changelog documentation:

> **md-input-container** renamed to **md-form-field** (while still being
>   backwards compatible). The old selector will be removed in a subsequent release.

Here is a link to complete [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

To use **`<md-form-field>`** selector, make sure that you have version 2.0.0-beta.10 of material installed. Moreover, you need to import **`MdFormFieldModule`** module in you **`AppModule`** imports:

```
import { MdFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    MdFormFieldModule,
    MdInputModule,
    ....
  ]
```

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, here is a link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-4uytww) on StackBlitz.

Comment: As an alternative for the OP's case, importing `MdInputModule` would work also, as that module re-exports `MdFormFieldModule`

Comment: I have material version 2.0.0-beta.3, and the MdFormFieldModule is not recognized for me. do you know why? the MdInputModule is recognized fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Batsheva because `MdFormFieldModule` was introduced in `2.0.0-beta.10` as I have stated in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! ok, I got it now, I thought you said version 1.0 so 3 it is ok...

Comment: Hey @Faisal thanks for your response - seems to be what I was looking for as well. Though using `2.0.0-beta.10` I am getting the error:

    `node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MdFormFieldModule'.` Thanks for any ideas in adnvace!

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding difficulties importing files then just you can have one methodology to import.

First import any required components in your .component.ts

And import the specific module in your module .module.ts

And then add it in imports in `@NgModule ({
imports : [ <Example>Module ]
})`

Example you want to import formcontrols just in you angular application

1). app.component.ts

```
`import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'`
```

2). app.module.ts

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'`

below in app.module.ts in

`@NgModule ({
imports : [ FormsModule ]
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use md-input-container like this :

```html
<md-input-container>
 <input mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="yourModel" class="filter-input-field"/>
</md-input-container>
```