# md-form-field must contain a MdFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to insert an input field in my component using `angular-material2`. This is my HTML:

```html
<md-form-field>
    <input type="text">
</md-form-field>
```

In the console, I get this error but I don't understand why I get the error:

> md-form-field must contain a MdFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add mdInput to the native input or textarea element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to import `MdFormFieldModule,MdInputModule` modules in your app.module. Then you need to add an `mdInput` directive in your `<input>`.

```
<md-form-field>
  <input type="text" mdInput>
</md-form-field>
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ct6zla?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Which version of material? Same error? Thats not possible - have you seen the demo?

Comment: Fixed it, i had forgotten to import some modules.

Comment: ...what modules?

Comment: `MdFormFieldModule`,`MdInputModule`  ... @MatthewMeppiel please upvote if this answer helped you :) please refer to this answer as well for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954825/1791913

Comment: I was already importing both of those modules and still received the error. I ended up viewing the link that you provided and just importing everything and it works. Was just curious as to which specific module needed to be added.

Comment: @Faisal, I imported MdFormFieldModule, MdInputModule and the code in the html is just like what you wrote. I don't get any errors, but the input looks as a regular html input, no floating label etc. do you have any idea why? I am using material beta.10

Comment: You need to add theme in your app.

Comment: What do you mean? as I mentioned I imported them in my app module