# md-form-field is not a known element Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'md-form-field' is not a known element:
 1. If 'md-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
of this module.
2. If 'md-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' 
to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

i have implemented angular input  with angular material

url https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

html

```
       <form class="example-form">
      <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
    </md-form-field>
    </form>
```

after googling i found link

> [Angular Material2 : 'md-form-field' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954397/angular-material2-md-form-field-is-not-a-known-element)

which says

```
  import { MdFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';

  @NgModule({
  imports: [
  ....
  MdFormFieldModule,
   ....
 ]
```

app.module.ts
after importing

> import { MdFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';

```
    ERROR in D:/frontend/src/app/app.module.ts (97,10): Module '"D:/frontendapp/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MdFormFieldModule'.
```

- can anyone suggest what im missing.

Comment: Make sure your `@angular/material` version is **2.0.0-beta.10** and there is no `MdFormFieldModule`,  just import `MdInputModule` and add it to imports array.

Comment: @Pengyy `MdFormFieldModule` was introduced in beta.10 and it has to be imported in module imports along with `MdInputModule`

Answer (score 1):

Import this module : MdInputModule 
Then use this code snip and enjoy :

```js
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput placeholder="User">
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` and `import {MdInputModule} from '@angular/material'` instead of **MdFormFieldModule** it's outdated.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ..
    ],
    imports: [
        MdInputModule,
        ..
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

To your module

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting that error in a more recent version of Angular, I found that [AngularMaterial indicates](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) it has changed the component tag (whatever you want to call it) from `md-form-field` to `mat-form-field` in recent versions. Notice the **mat** in `mat-form-field`. I was updating from version 2.0.0-beta.3 to version 5.2.5. [This breaking change appears to have come in 2.0.0-beta.12.](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-3)

While I needed to import `import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';` in my `app.module.ts` file, it was the component tag changes in the `.html` file that alleviated the console error `'md-form-field' is not a known element:`.

*Note: I came across this when upgrading my `md-input-container` tags to `md-form-field` tags, and it took me a lot of searching to realize that those have since been updated AGAIN to the new `mat-form-field`. Anyway, if you're updating from an old version of Material using `md-input-container` OR `md-form-field` to a newer version of Material, I would recommend you just update all the way to `mat-form-field` if you can.*

*Note2: Make sure to look out for any tangential updates - like changing directive names. For example, if you have any cases of `mdInput`, you'll likely need to change them to `matInput`. Stuff like that. Those `md` to `mat` changes may be prolific through your code. If your editor has a "replace-all" across multiple files functionality, it will be your best friend. At least `md` is not a common pair of letters, besides in the old AngularMaterial world.*