# What is the difference between the MdButton and MatButton in Angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Working on Angular 4 Material, couldn't find the exact difference between the MD components and MAT components. Is this depends upon the angular version weather to use MD or MAT components?

Comment: You can always read changelog, See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954397/template-parse-errors-md-form-field-is-not-a-known-element/45954825#45954825

Comment: Update to "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12" to fix this :)

Answer (score 3):

Please check this changelog, as Angular Material has made breaking changes from its beta.11 version to beta.12 version. `md` prefixes have been deprecated in favor of `mat` prefix.

More information [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix)