# There is no directive with exportAs set to matAutocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

**Error**

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete"
>   ("-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
>   [matAutocomplete]="auto">

I have used code from https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

I have also include in import in angular `app.module.ts`:

```
import { 
         MdAutocompleteModule,

  } from '@angular/material';
```

**Html component**

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
                {{ option }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**ng--version**

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 8.3.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animation: 4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/animations: 4.3.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
@angular/http: 4.3.2
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.2
@angular/router: 4.3.2
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
@angular/language-service: 4.3.2
```

can anyone suggest why angular is complaining about.

Comment: update your angular and material versions to 5+  ... you are using `@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8` which does not support `mat` prefix. The documents site from angular material uses the latest versions. If you want to keep using the same version, let me know, I'll post a version specific answer.

Comment: I have the exact some problem. I've got autocompletes up and running in one component, I want to use them in another component and I get this stuff thrown at me. Did you ever find out what was causing it?

Answer (score 4):

To use `mat-form-field`, you have to update your `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` versions to atleast [**2.0.0-beta.12**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954825/1791913). Use the following commands to update:

```
npm install @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12
npm install @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12
```

Then, you have import the following in your **`AppModule`**:

```
import { MatAutocompleteModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....
        MatAutocompleteModule, 
        MatFormFieldModule,
        ....
    ],
    ....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is a working [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-ejor4l?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) using version **2.0.0-beta.12**

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I had forgotten to import `MatAutocompleteModule` in my `AppModule`.